# Não consigo rodar o arquivo catalina.sh por problemas de permissão

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, catalina

Estou estudando sobre TomCat e estou tentando executar alguns comandos, dentre eles o catalina.sh.
Quando rodo o comando catalina start aparece o seguinte log de erro:

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
> Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
> Using CLASSPATH:
> /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar Using
> CATALINA_OPTS:    touch: cannot touch '/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out':
> Permission denied /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: 465: cannot create
> /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied

Pelo o que eu entendi deste log, é que dentro da pasta /opt/tomcat/logs/ ele tenta criar o arquivo catalina.sh mas por problemas de permissões ele não consegue.

Chequei as permissões de cada pasta e aparentemente era pra estar funcionando.

Permissões da pasta opt:

> drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  4096 Mar 20 21:22 opt

Permissões da pasta tomcat:

> drwxr-xr-x  9 root roge  4096 Mar 20 21:23 tomcat

Permissões da pasta logs:

> drwxr-xr-x 2 root roge  4096 Mar 21 16:00 logs

Única forma que eu consigo o arquivo catalina.out dentro da pasta logs é com o sudo.

Comment: Justamente, a permissão necessária é de escrita e como você pode ver pelas permissões que você listou, apenas o usuário root tem permissão de escrita. Por isso que funciona usando o `sudo`.

Comment: Eu estava na cabeça que ele precisa fazer a leitura do catalina.sh e não me liguei que ele precisa fazer a escrita pro log. Muito obrigado :D

Comment: Acontece :-D Feliz por ter ajudado :-)